# How to get BlueStacks 5's front camera to work in applications?

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

BlueStacks 5's back camera is now connected to my webcam, but the problem is that I want to use an application that has to verify my identity by taking a picture from the front camera. How do I get the front camera to work?

I've searched many places, adb or fake camera doesn't work at all. But sometimes I see they use Android studio, it can be set to choose that What will the front camera use and what will the rear camera use?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6edUN.png)

I want apps that require authentication to move to my back camera or my webcam.

Comment: If you need support with a product, [contact customer support](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In Windows you can globally enable/disable camera access for "apps" (which means programs and apps). Make sure this setting is enabled.